# Mixing cross-climate with winter/summer tires

Tags: tires

I'm tempted to change my seasonal tires to cross-climate ones, but I'm considering changing them progressively, to wear out my seasonal tires. Is it a very bad idea to let's say have on the front two cross-climate and on back two seasonal tires? I've heard mixed opinions, but does anybody have experience?

Comment: Seasonal tires? Cross climate, = all season ? Progressively? What does that mean what do you hope to accomplish ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having driven a car with four different tires, I know it is very unsafe to do so.  That being said, although different brands/makes of tires used in combination is not recommended, Continental Tires provides an excellent article on the subject.

https://www.continental-tires.com/car/tire-knowledge/tire-change-fitting/mixing-tires

PS: Some added info for your equatorial cracks:    https://wheelzine.com/what-causes-dry-rot-in-tires-how-to-fix-it